# Hide properties of Mongoose objects Typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm facing some issues with my code.

I have a Schema that basically looks like this interface.

```
export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  tokens: { token: string }[]
}
```

I wanna hide away the data that is returned by the .toJSON() using the only method that i know of which is:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj.password;
  return obj;
}
```

The only problem with this is the operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional. Which it shouldn't be. It should always be required.

Is there another way of solving this issue or do i have to make password optional?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how i solved this without modifiying the existing interface.

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const obj = this.toObject() as Partial<LeanDocument<IUser & Document>>;
  delete obj.password;
  return obj;
};
```